# Why does my Basic function is not working (in NodeJS)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

I'm working on a nodejs project and there is a little problem. I know the problem is not hard to solve but i've been searching for hours now and still didn't figure out how to solve it :

```
var gs = require('./gs1');
if (uncompressedDigitalLinkInput != "") {
    try {
        this.error3="";
        console.log("Test");
        gs.myfunction();
    } 
    catch(err) {
        this.error3=err+"\n"+err.stack;
        return "";
    }
} 
else {
    return "";
}
```

And the problem is the line  :

```
console.log("Test");
gs.myfunction();
```

Indeed, out of these two, only the console.log work. The other one doesn't.

Here is the code of "gs.myfunction"

```
class GS1DigitalLinkToolkit {
    function myfunction(){
        console.log('Function called');
    }
}
module.exports.myfunction = myfunction;
```

It tells me that "gs.myfunction is not a function". I have made sure that the require is the right path. So why it isn't working?

Comment: Can you please supply the error message you get?

Comment: @Phillip Yes thank you for your response, it tell me that "gs.myfunction is not a function"

Comment: I see you also just updated your code examples. Is `function myfunction() {...` really inside a class? That should be a syntax error. Move it outside the class, or make it a static method and export the whole class

Comment: @Phillip, Ok. i have moved it oustides the class and export the whole class, but the problem persist. I still have the same error messages

Comment: `class GS1DigitalLinkToolkit {
    function myfunction(){` this is not valid syntax to begin with. Post your real code instead of making things up here.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the method is callable only by an instance of GS1DigitalLinkToolkit. Two possible solutions can be:

1) Make the method static and export it as

```
class GS1DigitalLinkToolkit {
  static myfunction() {
      console.log('Function called');
  }
}

module.exports.myfunction = GS1DigitalLinkToolkit.myfunction
```

2) Import the class, make an instance and call the method on it

```
class GS1DigitalLinkToolkit {
    function myfunction(){
        console.log('Function called');
    }
}
module.exports.gsclass = GS1DigitalLinkToolkit;
```

and

```
var gs = require('./gs1');
if (uncompressedDigitalLinkInput != "") {
    try {
        this.error3="";
        console.log("Test");
        gs1 = new gs.gsclass();
        gs1.myfunction();
    } 
    catch(err) {
        this.error3=err+"\n"+err.stack;
        return "";
    }
} 
else {
    return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your main file `test.js`:

```
var gs = require('./gs1')
gs.myfunction();
```

And this required file `gs1.js`:

```
function myfunction() {
  console.log('Function called');
}

module.exports.myfunction = myfunction;
```

You should get:

```
$ node ./test.js
Function called
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. I know this is what i should got but instead i have a error message "TypeError: gs.myfunction is not a function"

Why ?

Comment: Are you saying that with the exact code from my answer you're still getting the error?

Comment: No i have integrated your code to my original code and the error is still on